# How can I switch which GitHub account is making a commit in a JetBrains IDE?

Tags: git, github, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I currently have 2 GitHub accounts, one for work and one for my personal projects, I use JetBrains suite of IDEs, on my work computer I've been signed in as my corporate GitHub account since I started, I recently wanted to clone one of my personal repos and work on it from my work computer, I added my personal account to my PyCharm IDE alongside my work account, cloned the repo, but whenever I make a commit to the repo the commit is marked as my work account.

Is there a way of quickly switching between the "active" account on a JetBrains IDE?

I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.4 & PyCharm 2023.1.2

I changed the default account for the project in the settings hoping that the next time I made a commit it would be marked correctly but no luck.